# Spatial panel data with splm: Error with univariate regression

Tags: r, spatial

I'm trying to estimate a spatial autoregressive model with areal data using the 'splm' package for R. When trying to perform a fixed-effects univariate regression prior to fitting the multivariate one, i stumbled upon the following error:

> `` Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "log(pcap)") : attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions ``

This does not occur when using either random effects or more than one independent variable. According to the package documentation of splm, this can also be reproduced using example data:

```
library('splm')
data(Produc, package="plm")
data(usaww)
# formula alike splm package documentation
fm.multi <- log(gsp)~log(pcap)+log(pc)
# univariate formula
fm.uni <- log(gsp)~log(pcap)
# works as expected
spml(fm.multi, data=Produc, listw=mat2listw(usaww), model="within")
# throws above error
spml(fm.uni, data=Produc, listw=mat2listw(usaww), model="within")
# also works
spml(fm.uni, data=Produc, listw=mat2listw(usaww), model="random")
```

Do I miss some specialities of spatial regression or R in general here or is this a bug in the splm-package?

Comment: This was indeed a bug in the splm package which is already solved in the version on R-forge and should be fixed in the next release.